# Is there a way to make systemd shutdown the system when a service exits with a particular code (e.g. exit code 0)?

Tags: debian, systemd, services

I have few Linux boxes each running a service. This is the only important process running on these machines. However, sometimes due to some internal state-changes in the service, it will gracefully stop itself with exit code 0. What I am looking for is an idiomatic way to shutdown the whole system when this happens. Basically I want the systemd to halt the system when myservice service exits with code 0, and restart myservice if it exits with a non-zero result code.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

`/etc/systemd/system/my_unit.service`:

```
[Unit]
...
...

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/your_program
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/systemctl poweroff
RestartSec=5
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
...
...
```

It's simple. Another interesting parameters see in `man systemd.service` and `man systemd.unit`.

Answer (score 3):

```
[Unit]
...

[Service]
Type=exec  # or any other type you want, apart from "oneshot"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/your_program
ExecStopPost=/bin/sh -c \
        'if [ "$SERVICE_RESULT" = "success" ]; then systemctl poweroff; fi'
RestartSec=5
Restart=on-failure
```

If your service is written using `Type=oneshot`, you will need the pattern in [Oxyd's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/572665/29483) instead.  Using `Type=oneshot` for a long-running service might not be very "idiomatic".  When the program is running, the state of such services will be shown as "starting", not "running".

Neither of these patterns are very elegant, but it's fairly easy to write and I think they should work OK :-).